# Python + XPath: Is it possible to select the next element after the one I actually want?

Tags: python, xpath

Suppose I have something like this:

```
<span class="filesize">File<a href="http://example.com/image.jpg" 
target="_blank">image.jpg</a>-(1.61 MB, 1000x1542, <span title="what the file is actually 
called.jpg">what the file is actually called.jpg</span>)</span><br><a href="http://example.com
/image.jpg" target="_blank">
```

What I want to extract from it is `http://example.com/image.jpg` and `what the file is actually called.jpg`. The constant term is the `<span class="filesize">File` which I can find using `xpath("span[text()='File']")` but that only gives me access to the `span`. Is there a way to do something like `result += 1` to go to the link afterward and then the `span` after it with the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `following-sibling` and `preceding-sibling` xpath "axes" to do the navigation you need.
You can get detains [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp).

**EDIT:**

Here's an example that gets me the result you want using only xpath. However it may not work for you depending on what the surrounding XML is like: (I've also had to complete some of the tags to be "real" XML. you may be able to get it working without doing that by putting your XML parser into HTML mode...)

```
import lxml.etree

xml = lxml.etree.XML("""<something><span class="filesize">File<a href="http://example.com/image.jpg" target="_blank">image.jpg</a>-(1.61 MB, 1000x1542, <span title="what the file is actually called.jpg">what the file is actually called.jpg</span>)</span><br/><a href="http://example.com/image.jpg" target="_blank"></a></something>""",)

print xml.xpath("a[preceding-sibling::span/text()='File']/@href")
```

Comment: I see now there are the `getnext()` and `getprevious()` methods. Is there a more pythonic way to use them inside the xpath, so that I don't have to access each element inside the list and make the code longer?

Comment: I've added more details on how I'd do it using only XPath.